# How do I get next item in array with each button click?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, arrays

I have a table in SQL with over 200 different fruit types in it. What I am doing is creating an application that surveys a user about these different fruit types, using the same group of questions. The application will first ask the user to choose from different fruit types. I store the values what the user selected and the count as a separate string and integer. Then I take the items they selected and display them one at a time with each button click. 
***CODE EDITED***

```
protected string[] FruitList;
```

Next I define a List to store the values from sql inside:

```
public class FruitList
{
    public int FruitID { get; set; }
    public string FruitName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the button click I get the count and retrieve the data from the database based on the values the user selected from the `asp:CheckBoxList`

```
List<FruitList> FruitList = new List<FruitList>();
StringBuilder myFruits = new StringBuilder();
string strFruits = string.Empty;
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem li in chkDepartments.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected == true)
    {
        strFruits += "'" + li.Value + "'" + ",";
        countFruits += 1;
        ActiveCount += 1;
    }
}

strFruits = strFruits.TrimEnd(',');
myFruits.Append("WHERE [id] IN(" + strFruits + ")");
if (countDeparments > 0)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer2"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select SELECT [ID], [Fruits] from [my_tastyfruits] " + myFruits, conn2);
        conn2.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader2.Read())
            {
                FruitList fl = new FruitList();
                fl.DeptID = reader2.GetInt32(0);
                fl.FruitName = reader2.GetString(1);
                FruitList.Add(fl);
            }
        }
        foreach (var fruits in FruitList)
        {
            //string[] FruitList = {"\"" + fruits.FruitName + "\"",};
            Array.Resize(ref FruitList, countFruits);
            FruitList[countFruits - 1] = fruits.FruitName; 
        }
        ViewState["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) + 1;
        txtNAC.Text = ViewState["count"].ToString();
        NAC = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]);
        Total = NAC - ActiveCount - 1;

        txtActiveCount.Text = FruitList[countFruits - 1];

        if (Total == 0)
        {
            NAC = 0;
            ActiveCount = 0;
            Response.Write("Congrats, The total is zero");
        }
        else if (Total >= 1)
        {
           Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }                    
    }
}
```

Currently This method only returns the last item in the array. It does not iterate the first or middle items in the array.

Comment: this is really unclear.  what exactly are you asking?  how to bind code to a button click?  if so that has nothing to do with sql-server.  How to write an update query -- if so what does that have to do with a button click.   Please make the question simpler so I (and people who can answer) know what you are asking.

Comment: No. I apologize for being unclear. I want to know how to get and display the next item in my array every time I click the button.

Comment: @Skullomania, Your code won't even compile, MyFruits is declared within your while loop so it is out of scope in your foreach loop. Even if you fixed this you would just be repeatedly creating a single element array and throwing it away in your foreach loop.

Comment: @BenRobinson I am compiling and testing my code currently without error while trying to figure out my own answer.

Comment: @Skullomania Can you clarify this for me please? "How do I then finally bind the two functions so that for each button click I can display the first, next(for how many the user selected) to last fruits that was stored in the array?" What kind of button is it? Since you said it was a survey I assumed you referred to radio buttons but know it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Skullomania when you fetch items (MyFruits) from sqlcommand, you are not filtering by type... (I assumed that each button displayed is a type) so how can you show any fruit related to button clicked?

Comment: @YanireRomero I edited the question. I hope this make it clearer

Comment: @Skullomania During execution what's the value for strFruits? And I strongly recommend naming improvements like: List<FruitList> FruitListVar = new List<FruitList>(); since it gets confusing.

Comment: @YanireRomero The value of strFruits is however many checkboxes the user has checked. The naming I chose here is not the name I am using in my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60481/discussion-between-yanire-romero-and-skullomania).