# How do I return one item at a time with each button click?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array that I declare above my form load:

```
protected string[] Colors = new string [3] {"red", "green", "orange"};
```

When I click this my submit I want to use a `Response.Write();` to print out `red` for the first click, `green` the second time I click it, then finally `orange` the last time I click it. I was reading [How do I get next item in array with each button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625272/how-do-i-get-next-item-in-array-with-each-button-click) and this user is trying to something very similar to what I am trying to do, however it looks as though the array in that case is dynamic.

Comment: This is embedded in ASP (so no state allowed)?

Comment: you need to keep a variable that counts how many clicks have been made

Comment: Ever heard about sessions?

Comment: You should really use a markup and code behind rather than writing out to the response stream directly.  It's far easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Track it in a session

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        int? count = Session["count"] as int?;
        count = (count == null) ? 0 : count;
        Response.Write(Colors[count.Value]);
        count = (count + 1) % Colors.Length;
        Session["count"] = count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use view state to keep track of some information through a request/response trail for a particular page.  You can store an index in the view state and then use that information when the button is clicked to see what should be printed to the screen.

Comment: It is possible to solve this without state. Every request one may return Colors[0] and than Colors = Colors.Skip(1).ToArray() until array is empty. For the described problem it is a proper solution.

Comment: @ValentinP. The instance field is created for every page request, so that would just print out the first item over and over again.

Comment: ok, I am not very familiar with asp.net (?). State is evil :).

Comment: @ValentinP. Strictly speaking `ViewState` is not storing any state between requests.  It's storing the state *within* the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Still looking for a solution to this and whilst doing so saw this pop up
This will get your button click amount:

```
ViewState["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) + 1;
```

As far as looping through the array I am still working on it. I have only been able to display the last item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the number of clicks in your ViewState and increase it by one in your button's click event handler.

```
private int NumberOfClicks
{
   get { return (int)(ViewState["NumberOfClicks"] ?? 0 );
   set { ViewState["NumberOfClicks"] = value; }
}


protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(NumberOfClicks < colorArray.Length)
   {
           //write to response colorArray[NumberOfClicks];
           NumberOfClicks += 1;
   }
}
```