# How do I cycle through items in my list object with each button click?

Tags: c#, webforms

In my (web forms) application I have defined defined my list

```
public class DepartmentList
{
    public int DeptID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I fill it with sql data. Note this code is within a button (submitdata) click :

```
using (SqlConnection conn2 = newSqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServer"].ConnectionString))
{
 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select [id], [Department] from Departments Where " + UserDefined + conn2);
conn2.Open();
using (SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader2.Read())
    {
        DepartmentList dl = new DepartmentList();
        dl.DeptID = reader2.GetInt32(0);
        dl.DepartmentName = reader2.GetString(1);
        DepartmentList.Add(dl);
    }
}
```

I have seen and tried the [example from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631079/how-do-i-return-one-item-at-a-time-with-each-button-click) here and it is very similar to what I want to do except in this example an array is being used and the array content and index is predefined. How do I do the same thing but instead use a List object and print each item out with each button (rotateData) click?

Comment: +1 as I have been trying to figure the same thing out. I have also been following your previous posts. Great question!

Comment: What button click? Is it ASP.Net webforms, MVC or WinForms? Be more descriptive please.

Comment: its asp.net webforms I apologize for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the position in the list somewhere and possibly the object collection.

It really depends on how the data is populated to the front end. I would follow an ajax approach to retrieve and populate using jQuery.

1. Create a function that returns json string for that department item based on index supplied in the call.
2. On the front end, store the current index in a javascript variable. When you press the button, make an ajax call to the function using current index, on success populate next item, increment the index.

I can provide a code example if needed.