# How do I call one item at a time stored in my list object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am creating an application using `ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms` for a friend who organizes parties and she wants to ask who will bring what(i.e. sides, meat, desert) to a list of her friends.

I already have a undetermined number of friends in stored in my index via `Microsoft SQL Management Studio` and usage of a `SQLDataReader`  :

```
public class FriendList
{
    public int FriendID { get; set; }
    public string FriendFullName { get; set; }
}
```

For starters, all I want to do is populate a `asp:Label` control with a different name from my list every time I click my `btnSubmit`. I was reading around this morning and found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631079/how-do-i-return-one-item-at-a-time-with-each-button-click), however in this example the array is static and my list is dynamic.

**EDITED**
This is what I need to have happen. Please keep in mind that I would have no knowledge of items in the list object because it was selected by the user. But for this example lets say that the user selected three names from the list presented. This is what I want to have happen, and this is what I cannot figure out how to do.

1st click "Emily"
2nd click "Madison"
3rd click "Jennifer"

Comment: What is your question? What part specifically are you having trouble with, reading the data, iterating over a list, assigning to the label text? Can you show more, relevant code?

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks so much for your reply! I am having trouble iterating over the list and assigning it to the label text as explained in the question. I would have included more code but all I have currently is my SQL statement and I felt posting that will distract from the question I am asking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get what your trying to do. I just figured it out a second ago it is very similar to what I have here. After posting this I will race to post it on my own. This will only work if like me you are using a checkboxlist:

```
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem li in chkFriends.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected == true)
    {
        strFriends += "'" + li.Value + "'" + ",";
        countFriends += 1;
    }
}
```

Then get the Viewstate number but minus one so it stays within the constraints of however many is selected.

```
int RAC = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) - 1;

if (RAC <= countFriends - 1)
{
    txtFriend.Text = FriendList[RAC].FriendName;
}
else
{
    //whatever you want (in a Constantine muppet voice)
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! also for the humor :)

Comment: Ah well, now I understand what you meant. Thought into a completely different direction...